# Graphviz: wrong node ordering in square lattice like graph using osage

Tags: graph, graphviz

I want to create a rectangular square lattice using GraphViz where all nodes are connected in both directions to their neighbors. The problem is, that if I use the terminal comand

```
osage -Tpng graph.gv > graph.png
```

to create this rectangular graph, the first and the last nodes are swapped. I checked all the links between the nodes and changing the position of node 0 and node 15 would yield the desired structure with correct connections. Here a small example of the resulting graph:

[image]

This issue also remains if I cancel all node-connections and only use the simple graph.gv file:

```
graph G {
0;
1;
2;
3;
4;
5;
6;
7;
8;
}
```

[image]

Up to 6 nodes, the node ordering is correct without any swap. For any higher node number, it gets mixed. I would expect osage to automatically correct the wrong ordering while adding the links between the nodes. But adding links does not change anything in the wrong ordering. I have also looked at possible attributes but could not find anything which would solve the problem.

Has anybody experienced a similar problem and can help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed.  This input

```
digraph grid {
0  1  2  3  
4  5  6  7  
8  9  10  11  
12  13  14  15  
0 -> 1
0 -> 4
1 -> 0
1 -> 2
1 -> 5
2 -> 1
2 -> 3
2 -> 6
3 -> 2
3 -> 7
4 -> 5
4 -> 0
4 -> 8
5 -> 4
5 -> 6
5 -> 1
5 -> 9
6 -> 5
6 -> 7
6 -> 2
6 -> 10
7 -> 6
7 -> 3
7 -> 11
8 -> 9
8 -> 4
8 -> 12
9 -> 8
9 -> 10
9 -> 5
9 -> 13
10 -> 9
10 -> 11
10 -> 6
10 -> 14
11 -> 10
11 -> 7
11 -> 15
12 -> 13
12 -> 8
13 -> 12
13 -> 14
13 -> 9
14 -> 13
14 -> 15
14 -> 10
15 -> 14
15 -> 11
}
```

And **osage** from Graphviz version 2.43.0 gives:
[image]